# Setting empty CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am trying to use a common library function to send GET and POST requests using curl.

```
function myCurl($url, $postData = null) 
{
    // Sets some default curl options here
    $options = array(
        ...
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
        ...
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    // this works and sends GET
    // unset($options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]); 

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

I want this function to send a POST if `$postData` is set, otherwise consider it a `GET`. However, this is sending POST even when I set the `CURL_POSTFIELDS` to `null`. Unsetting the `CURL_POSTFIELDS` options array element works and sends a `GET`. However, is there a way to keep the `CURL_POSTFIELDS` curl option and set it a default empty value and make it send `GET` requests?

Comment: Why do you need to send the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option?  It would be easy to just not include it in your options array at all if $postData is empty.

Comment: `$options = array(
        ...
    );   if ( !empty($postData) )  $options['CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS'] = $postData;`

Comment: I understand I can do a conditional check but I just wanted to know if there was a way to set an empty default

Comment: I don't think so.  When curl sees that option, it flags the response as a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$options = array(
    ...
);
if(!empty($postData)){
    $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]=$postData;
}
```

alternatively the following approach should works, but it's stupid imo:

```
$options = array(
    ...
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => empty($postData)
    ...
);
```

Comment: Perfect. The CURLOPT_HTTPGET was what I needed.

Comment: Having the CURLOPT_HTTPGET option after the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is of importance.